# raster::intersect not working in R

Tags: raster, r, point, intersection, rgeos

I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame and a raster for a region. I would like to retain only those points that occur within the elevational limits of the raster. Unfortunately, no points are being filtered. I still see points that occur outside of the 'masked extent' of the raster, although they occur within the overall extent of the raster.

Raster below:

```
> newelev
 class       : RasterLayer 
 dimensions  : 642, 382, 245244  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
 extent      : 461951, 843951, 892583.3, 1534583  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 data source : in memory
 names       : alt 
 values      : 1400, 2585.524  (min, max)
```

Below is my SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
> pr
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 262 
extent      : 529866.4, 798884.4, 945186.2, 1498039  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
names       :   X, pr 
min values  :   1,         1 
max values  : 899,         1
```

I use raster::intersect to obtain only points that occur within the elevational limits of the above raster.

```
> trial <- raster::intersect(pr,newelev)
> trial
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 262 
extent      : 529866.4, 798884.4, 945186.2, 1498039  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
names       :   X, pr 
min values  :   1,         1 
max values  : 899,         1
```

Below, you can see the plot, where points occur outside the masked extent of the elevation raster. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intersect` uses the extent of the RasterLayer to select the points. You can get what you are after like this:

```
v <- extract(newelev, pr)
p <- pr[!is.na(v), ]
```

Comment: Thanks @RobertH. That works. I realized that the intersect function simply ended up using the extent and was wondering if it excluded locations where  values == NA.